# Database fail to connect

Tags: database, ms-access, database-connection

I try to connect ms access database files named ShopTranfer.accdb but I got error "not a valid account name or password"

here is my connection string

```
Dim BD As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &
    con & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & pass & 
    ";Jet OLEDB:System Database=" & dir & ";"
```

BD actual value is

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
Source=c:\users\ahsan.gulahmed\desktop\shoptransfer.accdb;Jet
OLEDB:Database Password=a;Jet OLEDB:System
Database=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HMIS\Shop.mdw;
```

Comment: Well, it's telling you the username and password are not recognized. Are you sure you have the right username and password?

Comment: Yes I have opened my database file using password `a`

Answer (score 0):

use this url to get example of all contents..

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/828/thenewboston-sample-projects/

this is an good example for android api demos for all things......................